# How to fix issue calling Amazon SP-API, which always returns Unauthorized, even with valid Token and Signature

Tags: c#, api, integration, amazon-mws

I went through the guide of for getting setup to call the new SP-API (https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md), and during the process checked off all of the api areas to grant access to (i.e. Orders, Inventory, etc).  I am using the C# library provided by Amazon (https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-models/tree/main/clients/sellingpartner-api-aa-csharp).  I successfully get an access token and successfully sign the request, but always get the following error:

> Access to requested resource is denied.  / Unauthorized, with no details.

I am trying to perform a simple get to the **/orders/v0/orders** endpoint. What am I doing wrong?

Below is my code:

```
private const string MARKETPLACE_ID = "ATVPDKIKX0DER";
var resource = $"/orders/v0/orders";
var client = new RestClient("https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com");

IRestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(resource, Method.GET);

restRequest.AddParameter("MarketPlaceIds", MARKETPLACE_ID, ParameterType.QueryString);

restRequest.AddParameter("CreatedAfter", DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-5), ParameterType.QueryString);

var lwaAuthorizationCredentials = new LWAAuthorizationCredentials
{
    ClientId = AMAZON_LWA_CLIENT_ID,
    ClientSecret = AMAZON_LWA_CLIENT_SECRET,
    RefreshToken = AMAZON_LWA_REFRESH_TOKEN,
    Endpoint = new Uri("https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token")
};

restRequest = new LWAAuthorizationSigner(lwaAuthorizationCredentials).Sign(restRequest);

var awsAuthenticationCredentials = new AWSAuthenticationCredentials
{
    AccessKeyId = AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    SecretKey = AMAZON_ACCESS_SECRET,
    Region = "us-east-1"
};

restRequest = new AWSSigV4Signer(awsAuthenticationCredentials).Sign(restRequest, client.BaseUrl.Host);

var response = client.Execute(restRequest);
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue.  Have you made any progress on this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  However, I submitted a ticket to their support and supposedly it has been escalated to a principal engineer who is supposed to reach out.  If I get any resolution to this I will definitely post the details here.  Please let me know if you make any progress as well =)

Comment: Any updates anyone?  I can get the refresh token, checked the signature, checked credentials, but still getting the dreaded "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method".

Comment: Hi @david, did you figure it out? I'm facing the same problem, and my app is in Draft mode.

Comment: Hi. I'm moving onto this now and I guess you are missing the "Authorization" header. I must tell that Amazon SP-API documentation really sucks even because the provided Signer library actually doesn't sign anything: it just performs LWA authorization in order to get the AccessToken. I'll write the Sign process code tomorrow - I guess - and I'll let you know.

Comment: same issue here.. no resolution

Answer (score 3):

If you followed the SP-API guide, then you created a Role (which is the IAM ARN your app is registered with) and a User which has permissions to assume that role to make API calls.

However, one thing the guide is not clear about is that you can't make API calls using that user's credentials directly. You must first call the STS API's [AssumeRole method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) with your User's credentials (AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY_ID/AMAZON_ACCESS_SECRET), and it will return temporary credentials authorized against the Role. You use *those* temporary credentials when signing requests.

`AssumeRole` will also return a session token which you must include with your API calls in a header called `X-Amz-Security-Token`. For a brief description of `X-Amz-Security-Token` see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/CommonParameters.html

Answer (score 2):

You also get this error if your sp app is under review, drove me nuts!

Comment: does it apply if it's in draft status?

Comment: Yes, it does! This makes it so confusing!

Comment: does this also shown when app is approved but not released yet. status is "Ready For Publishing"

Answer (score 1):

If you using c# take look to

https://github.com/abuzuhri/Amazon-SP-API-CSharp

```
  AmazonConnection amazonConnection = new AmazonConnection(new AmazonCredential()
{
     AccessKey = "AKIAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
     SecretKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
     RoleArn = "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXX:role/XXXXXXXXXXXX",
     ClientId = "amzn1.application-XXX-client.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
     ClientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      RefreshToken= "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
 });
```

var orders= amazonConnection.Orders.ListOrders();

Comment: It looks like you've included a link to your own project, or a project you're affiliated with. If this is the case, [you *must* disclose your affiliation in the answer itself.](/help/promotion). Without this disclosure, your post could be considered spam.

Answer (score 0):

In our situation, we had to explicitly add an IAM policy to the user we defined as making the API call.  Please see the link below and confirm that the user you have calling the API has the policy assigned to them:

https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md#step-3-create-an-iam-policy

Somehow we went through the step-by-step setup twice, and adding this explicit policy was missed.  Initially I believe it was added 'inline' as instructed, but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think is a duplicated question, buy the solution may apply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66860192/1034622